# C++ Allocate memory for unknown no of objects read from file

Tags: c++, object, memory, text-files

How to create unknown no of objects at run time in C++, I am reading data from a text file and dont't want to waste any memory i.e No extra objects

```
Player* g_data()
{
    system("cls");
    char name[40];int level;
    fstream file;
    file.open("data.txt",ios::app|ios::in|ios::out);
    Player data[40],*ptr[100];
    int i=0;
    while(!file.eof()&&i<100)
    {
        file >>name>>level;
        strcpy(data[i].name,name);
        data[i].level=level;
        data[i].id=i;
        ptr[i]=&data[i];
        cout<<"Address-"<<ptr[i]<<"data"<<ptr[i]->name<<"id"<<ptr[i]->id<<endl;
        i++;
    }
    system("pause");
    return ptr[i-1];    
}
```

The thing is I need access to the memory location after I return the object and I don't want that memory to fade away, Now how can I allocate memory and access the memory throughout the program without wasting any.

Comment: What have you tried? It sounds like you need dynamic memory allocation with new and delete.

Answer (score 2):

If your text file is fixed-width, you can determine how many objects there are by dividing the file size by the size per object.

Modern systems rarely use fixed-width files.  In that case, your only alternative is to allocate memory by actually reading the file.  Read a line, allocate memory for the object represented by that line.  Continue until the file is entirely read.  No memory is wasted.

If you are trying to pre-allocate an array, don't.  Instead, dynamically allocate memory as you read in lines.

If you *must* use an array (e.g. homework constraint), you can read the file twice.  The first pass counts the number of objects that you need room for, you then allocate an array of appropriate size, then you read the file again to populate the array.  This is wasteful as it doubles the IO requirement of your algorithm.  Alternatively in this scenario, you can allocate an array with room for one element (or for the minimum number of elements that you expect), an then reallocate the array for each additional element that you read in.  This is rather inefficient in that it in general requires a new memory allocation and copying of the old array data to the new array memory for each new object.

Comment: That isn't the *only* option. He could also do a bunch of `realloc` calls or `new[]`, `memcpy`, `delete[]` calls.

Comment: You state it's inefficient, but you should include that `std::vector` works in exactly this way too. Also, it'd be interesting to compare whether it would be less efficient that the double file read.